# What is the Microsoft logo that shows up when viewing project.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When clicking the logo, it toggles between being visible on hover and being always visible. What is it meant to do? Is it some kind of indicator?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Subliminal merchandising?

Comment: @Jongware I found that Web Essentials is responsible for it, but I've yet to find the reason this was implemented. Your guess might just be the right one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just noticed that when clicking it, the status bar at the bottom says:

> Web Essentials: Global settings updated

It seems to be a new feature in Web Essentials:

> **Show logo watermarks in editor**
>   For certain files, a watermark of the associated logo is shown in the top right corner.

[Currently](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/blob/ae679e3f769b3cadf4b5a83c2ce39c5febb71c95/EditorExtensions/JSON/Adornments/LogoProvider.cs) it shows a logo for 5 files:

```
{ "bower.json", "bower.png"},
{ "package.json", "npm.png"},
{ "project.json", "vs.png"},
{ "gruntfile.js", "grunt.png"},
{ "gulpfile.js", "gulp.png"},
```